# calculations with the Riemann curvature

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, notation, riemannian-geometry

I was doing a calculation with the Riemann tensor and in a part of that calculation I got these terms 
$+\frac{\alpha}{4}R_{ijl}^qRm^2_{kq}-\frac{\alpha}{2}R_{ijk}^qRm^2_{ql}$
where $Rm^2$ is the $(2,0)$-tensor given by $Rm_{ij}^2:=R_{iklm}R_j^{klm}$. I´m not so familiar with de $*-$notation. Is it correct if I write those terms as $Rm*Rm^2$?. Where could I get information about the rules of $*-$notation?
Thanks!

Comment: Check my former advisor's book: _Riemannian Geometry_ by Peter Petersen.  GTM series.